# error in defining a subview in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error, undefined, notice

this is my controller

```
public function index() {
    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_login_model->get();
    $this->data['abc'] = 'admin/user/index';
    $this->load->view ( 'admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

this is my view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- main column -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">

        <?php $this->load->view($abc);?>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is the error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: abc
>
> Filename: admin/_layout_main.php
>
> Line Number: 31 An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: .php

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
$data['users'] = $this->user_login_model->get();
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/user/index', $data, true);
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
```

By this way you can use your **view** and **template** in **controller** function.